# Deploy storm topology on pseudo cluster server

Tags: apache-storm

I install the storm on one single sever. I'm pretty sure the zookeeper, nimbus, supervisor and ui services are all running properly, cause i can see those processes and also can view the UI from the browser.
The storm java code can run in the eclipse as expected, you can reference the code below to find out the difference on local and remote mode.

```
if(args.length == 0)
    {
        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology(TOPOLOGY_NAME, config, builder.createTopology());
        Utils.waitForSeconds(10);
        cluster.killTopology(TOPOLOGY_NAME);
        cluster.shutdown();
    }
    else{
        StormSubmitter.submitTopology(args[0], config, builder.createTopology());
    }
```

But unfortunately, i got the error below when i deploy the jar file to the one single server.

> 1797 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.a.AuthUtils - Got AutoCreds []
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException
>       at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitJarAs(StormSubmitter.java:439)
>       at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyAs(StormSubmitter.java:236)
>       at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:311)
>       at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:157)
>       at storm.blueprints.chapter1.v3.WordCountTopology.main(WordCountTopology.java:39)
>   Caused by: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException
>       at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
>       at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
>       at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:129)
>       at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
>       at org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
>       at org.apache.storm.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
>       at org.apache.storm.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
>       at org.apache.storm.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
>       at org.apache.storm.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77)
>       at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.recv_beginFileUpload(Nimbus.java:1007)
>       at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.beginFileUpload(Nimbus.java:995)
>       at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitJarAs(StormSubmitter.java:410)
>       ... 4 more

The command which i used for deployment are below:

```
/usr/share/storm/bin/storm jar ./storm-sample1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar storm.blueprints.chapter1.v3.WordCountTopology word-count
```

Comment: This problem can be fixed by running the storm nimbus, supervisor, and ui directly from the command line, then i can submit the storm jar file to the server. I met the problem above if i use the Linux(Ubuntu) supervisor to load up the storm nimbus, supervisor and ui daemon processes. I'm still trying to figure out how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem actually caused by the account that is used to run the storm daemon. When the time you deploy the topology to the cluster, make sure the account/user that is used to run the storm daemon has sufficient access right to the folder(storm.local.dir: "/home/storm") you created in the storm.yaml file. also the log folder.